# Valid values for a xorg.conf(5) Monitor Identifier?

Tags: linux, xorg, monitors

I have a Dell P2210 monitor. Its EDID data is somewhat conservative.

I am currently using the following file, which works as expected:

```
# Ubuntu: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-DELL_P2210.conf
# Other: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-DELL_P2210.conf
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DisplayPort-0"
#   VendorName "Dell"
#   ModelName "P2210"
    Modeline "1680x1050_74.00"  148.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1088  -HSync +VSync
    Option "PreferredMode" "1680x1050_74.00"
EndSection
```

However, this is, obviously, *quite* fragile: it is bound to my GPU and precise cabling setup. It will break if I move the monitor to another port, or switch out my GPU for one with different sockets or different RandR namings.

I want to use an *actual monitor identifier* in the Identifier field of this Monitor directive, rather than the *port identifier* which is currently in-use.

I have already scoured the [`xorg(5)` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/xorg.conf.5.html); it had the following to say (emphasis added):

> The only mandatory entry in a `Monitor` section is the `Identifier` entry.
>
> The `Identifier` entry specifies the unique name **for this monitor**. The `Monitor` section may be used to provide information about the specifications of the monitor, monitor‑specific `Options`, and information about the video modes to use with the monitor.
>
> With RandR 1.2-enabled drivers, monitor sections **may** be tied to specific outputs  of the video card…by adding an option to the `Device` section…

But I cannot find any semantically correct values for this field *that are valid*!

```
[    60.634] (II) AMDGPU(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: 404d  Serial#: 1129597523
…
[    60.634] (II) AMDGPU(0): Serial No: U828K94ICTJS
[    60.635] (II) AMDGPU(0): Monitor name: DELL P2210
…
[    73.031] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 16461
```

```
[    51.733] (II) RADEON(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: 404d  Serial#: 1129597523
…
[    51.733] (II) RADEON(0): Serial No: U828K94ICTJS
[    51.733] (II) RADEON(0): Monitor name: DELL P2210
…
[    70.009] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 16461
```

I have already tried every combination I can think of of monitor model, name, vendor, etc., [but none of these works](http://ix.io/3OHf); *only* `"DisplayPort-0"` does.

I don't like having configurations on my system held together by duct tape that will require bus_factor=1 knowledge (or a lot of investigation) plus a drop of experienced Linux engineering labor to restore or repair if someone (future-self included) does something *utterly reasonable* such as moving the monitor to another port if the current one gets damaged.

I want to put a *monitor identifier* in the *Monitor's Identifier*, rather than the *port identifier* that is currently in there. What value will serve this purpose? I do *not* want to risk this configuration ever being erroneously applied to a monitor of a different model than this one, nor this configuration failing to apply to this monitor in the event of some reasonable change affecting its port.

Generally speaking, what values *are valid* in the `Identifier` field of a `Monitor` section within xorg configuration? Are there any that can be used to uniquely identify a monitor (up to either model or serial number specificity), or *at least* to defer such identification to other fields such as `ModelName` and `VendorName`? The manpage—which I have read—lacks an answer to this question.

(I am asking from Ubuntu MATE 20.04 today, but this is something that I've been wondering in the back of my mind for years across several other distributions including Fedora, Arch Linux, and Gentoo, so I believe it's not a distribution-specific quirk.)